# Passing argument to function in model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, casting, eloquent

I have following method in my controller.

```
public function show($semester_name = null)
        {
            $semester = $this->getSemester($semester_name);

            $matches = Match::GetMatches($semester->id);

            $semesters = Semester::where('active', 1)->orderBy('name')->get();

            return view('entities/match.indexMatched', compact('matches', 'semesters'));
        }
```

And this method in my model:

```
public function scopeGetMatches($id)
        {
            $query = "SELECT

                        some code...

                        WHERE matches.semester_id       = " . $id . "   
                        ORDER BY 2, 3, 5, 6 
                        ";

            return DB::select(DB::raw($query));
        }
```

But I get the error `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string`.

I know for sure I get a valid $semester->id.

Help someone?

Comment: $matches = Match::GetMatches($semester->id); what does it do ??

Comment: or can you post where the error occurs as your question is not so much clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of scope method accept as first parameter instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, so your method should look
 like:

`public function scopeGetMatches(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder, $id)`

Basically scope method should modify state of your current model querying, because scope methods are passing between each other with current instance of query builder for this model - for example:

`Posts::where('published', true)->newest()->get()`

`public function scopeNewest($builder) {
    $builder->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}`

Is same as:

`Posts::where('published', true)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get()`

So implementation of yours is wrong and can be just a static method.

You can find more on Laravel Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#query-scopes.

Comment: Thank you, sir.
I just made the metod static.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$semesters = Semester::where('active','=','1')->orderBy('name')->get();
```